# Loop pages and download pdf files from website in Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to download pdf files from this [link](https://www.savills.com.cn/insight-and-opinion/research.aspx?rc=China&p=%E5%95%86%E4%B8%9A%E6%A5%BC%E5%AE%87&t=&f=date&q=&page=1),

[image]

By far I'm able to download one file using the following code:

```
import shutil
import requests
import os
from urllib.parse import urlparse

url = "http://pdf.savills.asia/asia-pacific-research/china-research/shanghai-research/shanghai-office/20q1-sh-office-cn.pdf"
# file_name = url.split("/")[-1]
file_name = os.path.basename(urlparse(url).path)

r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
r.raw.decode_content = True

with open("20q1-sh-office-cn.pdf", 'wb') as f:
        shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
# with open("./{}".format(file_name), 'wb') as f:
#     shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

But now I don't how to find and extract all url links of pdf files and download them, I have tried the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.savills.com.cn/insight-and-opinion/research.aspx?rc=China&p=%E5%95%86%E4%B8%9A%E6%A5%BC%E5%AE%87&t=&f=date&q=&page={}'
for page in range(10):
    r = requests.get(url + str(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    for link in soup.find_all("a"):
        print("<a href='>%s'>%s</a>" % (link.get("href"), link.text))
```

Note that xpath of pdf file's url is: `//*[@id="ListingContainer"]/div[1]/article[1]/div[1]/div/header/h3/a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have BS 4.7.1 or above try following css selector to get the pdf links.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.savills.com.cn/insight-and-opinion/research.aspx?rc=China&p=%E5%95%86%E4%B8%9A%E6%A5%BC%E5%AE%87&t=&f=date&q=&page={}'
for page in range(2):
    r = requests.get(url.format(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    for link in soup.select("h3[class='sv-card-title']>a"):
        print(link.text)
        print(link.get("href"))
```

---

**Update**:

```
import shutil
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import os
from urllib.parse import urlparse

url = 'https://www.savills.com.cn/insight-and-opinion/research.aspx?rc=China&p=%E5%95%86%E4%B8%9A%E6%A5%BC%E5%AE%87&t=&f=date&q=&page={}'
for page in range(2):
    r = requests.get(url.format(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    for link in soup.select("h3[class='sv-card-title']>a"):
        r = requests.get(link.get("href"), stream=True)
        r.raw.decode_content = True
        with open(link.text+'.pdf', 'wb') as f:
            shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Could you please integrate your code with download part? I want use `file_name` or `link.text` as pdf files' name.

Comment: I tested with your updated code, it could iterate urls and download files, but file format is not pdf, so i can't open them. Could test it please?

Comment: @ahbon : Just add the extension as pdf.Check updated code.

Comment: Btw, how could I get `h3[class='sv-card-title']>a`? I think this is the key to extract links.

Comment: @ahbon : This is `css` selector as i have mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution based on KunduK's:

```
import shutil
import requests
import os
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def download_pdf(file_name, url):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

    with open("./{}.pdf".format(file_name), 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)

url = 'https://www.savills.com.cn/insight-and-opinion/research.aspx?rc=China&p=%E5%95%86%E4%B8%9A%E6%A5%BC%E5%AE%87&t=&f=date&q=&page={}'
for page in range(2):
    r = requests.get(url.format(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    for link in soup.select("h3[class='sv-card-title']>a"):
        print(link.text)
        print(link.get("href"))
        download_pdf(link.text, link.get("href"))
```